Information not appearing after button click ASP .NET Core MVC
I currently have a view page that displays language information in a table and an edit link that will take me to a new view page to edit the language information. I'm trying to make everything stay on one page so the user doesn't get confused. I've tried using Html.RenderPartial which will render the view but doesn't bring the information with it. I've ran out of ideas that make this work, any help is appreciated.
Controller:
public IActionResult LanguageUpdate (int id)
{
    OfficerLangVM lang = getLanguage(id);

    return View(lang);
}

[HttpPost]
public IActionResult UpdateLang(OfficerLangVM UpdateLang)
{
    MailkitErrors errors = new(ServiceProvider!, Configuration!);

    UserEmail = HttpContext.Session.GetString("UserEmail")!;

    string ConnectionString = connectionStrings.Get("ForeignLanguageConnectString");

    var objLangUpdateConnect = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
    var objLangUdDataSet = new DataSet();
    string strLangUpdate = "UpdateLanguage";
    try
    {
        var objCommandlang = new SqlCommand(strLangUpdate, objLangUpdateConnect);
        objCommandlang.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        //Add parameters for input
        objCommandlang.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RowCount", 1);
        objCommandlang.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OfficerKey", UpdateLang.OfficerKey);
        objCommandlang.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LanguageKey", UpdateLang.LanguageKey);
        objCommandlang.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LanguageName", UpdateLang.LanguageName);
        objCommandlang.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Fluency", UpdateLang.Fluency);
        objCommandlang.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CanRead", UpdateLang.CanRead);
        objCommandlang.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CanWrite", UpdateLang.CanWrite);
        objCommandlang.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CanSpeak", UpdateLang.CanSpeak);
        objCommandlang.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CanUnderstand", UpdateLang.CanUnderstand);
        objCommandlang.Parameters.Add("@UserUpdated", SqlDbType.VarChar, 150).Value = "";

        var ObjDataAdapterLang = new SqlDataAdapter(objCommandlang);
        ObjDataAdapterLang.Fill(objLangUdDataSet, "Language"); //FLIPV2 dbo.Language Table
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        ViewBag.ErrorMessage = "There has been an error. MAGLOCLEN HelpDesk has been notified.";
        errors.ErrorEmails(UserEmail, "Error occured while updating language for selected officer:\n");
    }

    UpdateLang.Officer = getOfficer(UpdateLang.OfficerKey);
    UpdateLang.syncOfficer();
    return Redirect("LanguageUpdate/" + UpdateLang.LanguageKey);     
}

//Delete language from Database
public IActionResult DeleteLang(int id)
{
    MailkitErrors errors = new(ServiceProvider!, Configuration!);

    UserEmail = HttpContext.Session.GetString("UserEmail")!;

    OfficerLangVM deleteLang = getLanguage(id);

    string ConnectionString = connectionStrings.Get("ForeignLanguageConnectString");

    var objLangDelConnect = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
    var objLangDelDataSet = new DataSet();
    string strLangDelete = "DeleteLanguage";
    try
    {
        var objCommandlang = new SqlCommand(strLangDelete, objLangDelConnect);
        objCommandlang.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        //Add parameters for input
        objCommandlang.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RowCount", 1);
        objCommandlang.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LanguageKey", deleteLang.LanguageKey);
        objCommandlang.Parameters.Add("@Username", SqlDbType.VarChar, 150).Value = "debug";

        var ObjDataAdapterLang = new SqlDataAdapter(objCommandlang);
        ObjDataAdapterLang.Fill(objLangDelDataSet, "Language"); //FLIPV2 dbo.Language Table
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        ViewBag.ErrorMessage = "There has been an error. MAGLOCLEN HelpDesk has been notified.";
        errors.ErrorEmails(UserEmail, "Error occured while deleting language from officer:\n");
    }

    return RedirectToAction("Editing", new { id = deleteLang.OfficerKey });
}

LangInfo View Page:
@model OfficerLangVM

<body>
    <div class="full-width">
        <h4>Language Information</h4>
        <table style="background-color:lightgray; width:75%" class="table table-boardered table-striped" cellpadding="5">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Language</th>
                    <th>Fluency</th>
                    <th>Read</th>
                    <th>Write</th>
                    <th>Speak</th>
                    <th>Understand</th>
                    <th>Date Modified</th>
                    <th><!--Edit--></th>
                    <th><!--Delete--></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <input type="hidden" asp-for="OfficerKey" />
                <input type="hidden" asp-for="AgGuid" />
                <input type="hidden" asp-for="LanguageKey"/>
                @{
                    if (Model.Languages != null)
                        foreach (Language lang in Model.Languages)
                        {
                                <tr id="Info">
                                    <td>@lang.LanguageName</td>
                                    <td>@lang.Fluency</td>
                                    @if (lang.CanRead == true)
                                    {
                                        <td><input type="checkbox" checked="checked" /></td>
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
                                    }
                                    @if (lang.CanWrite == true)
                                    {
                                        <td><input type="checkbox" checked="checked" /></td>
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
                                    }
                                    @if (lang.CanSpeak == true)
                                    {
                                        <td><input type="checkbox" checked="checked" /></td>
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
                                    }
                                    @if (lang.CanUnderstand == true)
                                    {
                                        <td><input type="checkbox" checked="checked" /></td>
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
                                    }
                                        <td>@lang.DateUpdated</td>
                                        <td>
                                            <!--Testing to keep user on same view page, doesn't pull an info-->
                                            <input type="button" value="testing" onclick="show(@lang.LanguageKey); hide()"/> 
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <!--This works just takes user to new view page-->
                                            <a asp-action="LanguageUpdate" asp-route-id="@lang.LanguageKey">Edit</a>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <a asp-action="DeleteLang" asp-route-id="@lang.LanguageKey">Delete</a>
                                        </td>
                                </tr>

                                <!--Toggle between divs, LanguageUpdate doesn't work (WIP)-->
                                <tr style="display:none" id="@lang.LanguageKey">
                                @{
                                    Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/Agency/LanguageUpdate.cshtml");
                                }
                                </tr>
                        }
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function show(key) {
            document.getElementById(key).style.display = "block";
        }

        function hide() {
            document.getElementById("Info").style.display = "none";
        }
    </script>

    <style>

        .body-container {
            /*remove the container default padding attribute*/
            /*padding-left: 0px !important;
                    padding-right: 0px !important;*/
            /*increase width as per your need*/
            max-width: 100%;
        }
    </style>

</body>

LanguageUpdate View:
@model OfficerLangVM

<form asp-action="UpdateLang" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" asp-for="OfficerKey" />
    <input type="hidden" asp-for="AgGuid" />
    <input type="hidden" asp-for="LanguageKey" />
    @{
        if (Model != null)
        {
            <td>
                <select asp-for="LanguageName">
                    <option Value=""> 1) Select a Language . . .</option>
                    <option value="American Sign English (ASE)">American Sign English (ASE)</option>
                    <option value="American Sign Language (ASL)">American Sign Language (ASL)</option>
                    <option value="Arabic: Algerian">Arabic: Algerian</option>
                    <option value="Arabic: Egyptian">Arabic: Egyptian</option>
                    <option value="Awadhi">Awadhi</option>
                    <option value="Azerbaijani">Azerbaijani</option>
                    <option value="Bengali">Bengali</option>
                    <option value="Bhojpuri">Bhojpuri</option>
                    <option value="Chinese: Cantonese">Chinese: Cantonese</option>
                    <option value="Chinese: Fukein">Chinese: Fukein</option>
                    <option value="Chinese: Jinyu">Chinese: Jinyu</option>
                    <option value="Chinese: Mandarin">Chinese: Mandarin</option>
                    <option value="Chinese: Min Nan">Chinese: Min Nan</option>
                    <option value="Chinese: Wu">Chinese: Wu</option>
                    <option value="Creole">Creole</option>
                    <option value="Creole-Jamaican">Creole-Jamaican</option>
                    <option value="Czech">Czech</option>
                    <option value="Dutch">Dutch</option>
                    <option value="Esperanza">Esperanza</option>
                    <option value="Estonian">Estonian</option>
                    <option value="Farsi">Farsi</option>
                    <option value="French">French</option>
                    <option value="Gaelic">Gaelic</option>
                    <option value="German">German</option>
                    <option value="Greek">Greek</option>
                    <option value="Hausa">Hausa</option>
                    <option value="Hebrew">Hebrew</option>
                    <option value="Hindi">Hindi</option>
                    <option value="Hmong">Hmong</option>
                    <option value="Hungarian">Hungarian</option>
                    <option value="Icelandic">Icelandic</option>
                    <option value="Italian">Italian</option>
                    <option value="Japanese">Japanese</option>
                    <option value="Kannada">Kannada</option>
                    <option value="Korean">Korean</option>
                    <option value="Lao">Lao</option>
                    <option value="Latin">Latin</option>
                    <option value="Maithili">Maithili</option>
                    <option value="Marathi">Marathi</option>
                    <option value="Malayalam">Malayalam</option>
                    <option value="Native American: Blackfoot">Native American: Blackfoot</option>
                    <option value="Native American: Cheyenne">Native American: Cheyenne</option>
                    <option value="Native American: Chippewa">Native American: Chippewa</option>
                    <option value="Native American: Cree">Native American: Cree</option>
                    <option value="Native American: Dakota">Native American: Dakota</option>
                    <option value="Native American: Lakota">Native American: Lakota</option>
                    <option value="Native American: Lenape">Native American: Lenape</option>
                    <option value="Native American: Navajo">Native American: Navajo</option>
                    <option value="Native American: Ojibwi">Native American: Ojibwii</option>
                    <option value="Native American: Oneida">Native American: Oneida</option>
                    <option value="Native American: Onodaga">Native American: Onodaga</option>
                    <option value="Native American: Paivte">Native American: Paivte</option>
                    <option value="Native American: Shoshoni">Native American: Shoshoni</option>
                    <option value="Native American: Sioux">Native American: Sioux</option>
                    <option value="Niger-Congo: Akan">Niger-Congo: Akan</option>
                    <option value="Niger-Congo: Twi">Niger-Congo: Twi</option>
                    <option value="Norwegian">Norwegian</option>
                    <option value="Oriya">Oriya</option>
                    <option value="Panjabi">Panjabi</option>
                    <option value="Patois">Patois</option>
                    <option value="Polish">Polish</option>
                    <option value="Portuguese">Portuguese</option>
                    <option value="Romanian">Romanian</option>
                    <option value="Russian">Russian</option>
                    <option value="Serbian">Serbian</option>
                    <option value="Serbo-croatian">Serbo-croatian</option>
                    <option value="Sign Language">Sign Language</option>
                    <option value="Sindhi">Sindhi</option>
                    <option value="Slovaic(Slovak)">Slovaic(Slovak</option>
                    <option value="Spanish">Spanish</option>
                    <option value="Sunda">Sunda</option>
                    <option value="Swedish">Swedish</option>
                    <option value="Tagalog">Tagalog</option>
                    <option value="Tamil">Tamil</option>
                    <option value="Telugu">Telugu</option>
                    <option value="Thai">Thai</option>
                    <option value="Turkish">Turkish</option>
                    <option value="Ukrainian">Ukrainian</option>
                    <option value="Urdu">Urdu</option>
                    <option value="Vietnamese">Vietnamese</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <select asp-for="Fluency">
                    <option value="1) Limited Proficiency">1. Limited Proficiency</option>
                    <option value="2) Novice">2. Novice</option>
                    <option value="3) Intermediate">3. Intermediate</option>
                    <option value="4) Advanced">4. Advanced</option>
                    <option value="5) Native Speaker">5. Native Speaker</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            @if (Model.CanRead == true)
            {
                <td>
                    @Html.CheckBoxFor((modelItem => Model.CanRead))
                </td>
            }
            else
            {
                <td>
                    @Html.CheckBoxFor((modelItem => Model.CanRead))
                </td>
           }
           @if (Model.CanWrite == true)
           {
                <td>
                    @Html.CheckBoxFor((modelItem => Model.CanWrite))
                </td>
           }
           else
           {
               <td>
                   @Html.CheckBoxFor((modelItem => Model.CanWrite))
               </td>
           }
           @if (Model.CanSpeak == true)
           {
                <td>
                    @Html.CheckBoxFor((modelItem => Model.CanSpeak))
                </td>
           }
           else
           {
                <td>@Html.CheckBoxFor((modelItem => Model.CanSpeak))</td>
           }
           @if (Model.CanUnderstand == true)
           {
                <td>
                    @Html.CheckBoxFor((modelItem => Model.CanUnderstand))
                </td>
           }
           else
           {
                <td>@Html.CheckBoxFor((modelItem => Model.CanUnderstand))</td>
           }
           <td>@Model.DateUpdated</td>
           <td>
                <input type="submit" value="Update" class="btn btn-primary" style="background-color:lightgray; color:black" />
           </td>
           <td>
                <input type="submit" value="Delete" class="btn btn-primary" style="background-color:lightgray; color:black" asp-action="DeleteLang" asp-route-id="@Model.LanguageKey" />
           </td>
           <td>
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" asp-action="Editing" asp-route-id="@Model.OfficerKey" value="Cancel" style="background-color:lightgray; color:black" />
           </td>            
        }
    }

    <!--<p>Edit the details of the selected officer and click the <b>Update</b> link in the grid above to save the changes, or click the <b>Delete</b>
                link to permanently delete this item.
            <p>Click the <b>Cancel</b> link to abandon any changes made to the item.</p>-->
            
</form>

    <style>

        .body-container {
            /*remove the container default padding attribute*/
            /*padding-left: 0px !important;
                    padding-right: 0px !important;*/
            /*increase width as per your need*/
            max-width: 100%;
        }
    </style>





You need to pass the OfficerLangVM model to the LanguageUpdate View like :
<tr style="display:none" >
    @{
        Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/Agency/LanguageUpdate.cshtml",Model);
    }
</tr>

You can read Access data from partial views to know more.

I tried doing this and it doesn't return everything. I'm assuming it's because the language information is stored in the Language model, the OfficerLangVM is a view model. I tried to pass the Language model through but it keeps giving me an error The model item passed into the ViewDataDictionary is of type 'CoreApp.Models.Language', but this ViewDataDictionary instance requires a model item of type 'CoreApp.Models.OfficerLangVM'.

@mag232913  What's your OfficerLangVM model like ?

I was able to get it to work.
